# Vim problem installing python 3.5 from source

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, vimscript-python

I have installed python 3.5 from the official source, and everything was working.  I decided to try vim as a sort of command line IDE. Most plugins worked with vim, but when I tried `YouCompleteMe` for text completion, vim had this import error in `messages`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 22, in <module>
  File "/home/jack/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/base.py", line 27, in <module>
    from ycm import vimsupport
  File "/home/jack/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/vimsupport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ycmd.utils import ( GetCurrentDirectory, JoinLinesAsUnicode, ToBytes,
  File "/home/jack/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/python/ycm/../../third_party/ycmd/ycmd/utils.py", line 30, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 49, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-35m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: PyByteArray_Type
```

[This thread](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2427) tells me that it isn't a problem with `vim` or `YouCompleteMe`, but a problem with the compatability between vim and my compilation of python 3.5.  What are the differences between the package for python 3.3 that is in `apt-get` and the python 3.5 straight from python's website?  What are the additions that are made in the package that make it more compatible with vim?  Is there a special way to make python 3.5 compatible with vim and other linux features that I have not found yet?

Basically, what would I have to do to make python 3.5 compatible with vim?

I'm on a raspberry pi running raspbian jessie.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with Rasberry Pi but how about try to install python 3.5 using apt-get? I found that it's available in repository: http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/p/python3.5/

Comment: Hmm I didn't think that there wasn't a package for python 3.5.  I'll check with `apt-cache`.

Comment: Nothing came up when I used `sudo apt-cache search python3.5` maybe update your answer to include how to add the repository in the link.  From the output of `sudo apt-get update` it looks like it just gets updates from the [jessie](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/) archive.

Comment: Ok, after researching why python3.5 wasn't in apt, I found [this](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=python3.5) which explains why it wasn't in apt-get.